# How to change location of a progress bar?

Tags: javascript, html

I created a progress bar for a game I'm making. But the bar is at the top left of the browser and I would like to move the bar elsewhere but I'm not sure how to do this.

```
<progress id="health" value="1000" max="1000"></progress>
```

Comment: First you have to know what you want. We talk later.

Comment: "Elsewhere" is **very** vague.

Comment: I've added a comment on one of the answers below to further clarify. Elsewhere is probably the wrong word but In general I just wanted to know how to move the location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `position:fixed` and the CSS attributes `top`, `left`, `right` and `bottom` to position it like so:

```css
progress{
  position:fixed;
  top:40%;
  left:40%;
}
progress::before{
  content:"hey look im floating";
}
```

```html
<progress id="health" value="1000" max="1000"></progress>
```

Comment: I have a canvas that's 950px in width and 750 in height. Whenever I zoom in or out the bar location moves relative to the screen size. Is there a way to keep the bar inside the canvas in the same position. I moved the bar to top: 80px, and left:510px. This makes the bar appear on the top left of my canvas where I want to keep it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with CSS `position: absolute`:

```css
#health {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px; /* moves the progress bar to the bottom-right */
    right: 0px;
}
```

```html
<progress id="health" value="1000" max="1000"></progress>
```